# squash commit in git

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a feature/branch which has over 280 commits. The feature/branch was continuously merged to develop along the way.

I did not squash the commits every time the feature was merged to develop.

I could manually squash in the feature branch using `git rebase -i HEAD~<noOfCommitsToBeSquashed>` and then update the commit message and merge.

My question is what would happen once I squash several commits in the feature branch and then merge it to develop? Would the total number of commits in the develop would decrease?

How does it work? The ultimate issue I am trying to solve is that I am having to use `GIT_DEPTH=1000` due to the number of commits in develop. And this causes (is why I think) taking the job more time to finish

I would appreciate it if anyone could guide me here. Thank you

Comment: As the `feature` branch has already been merged into `develop`, squashing its commits would not have any effect on `develop` except create a conflict hell when trying to merge again into `develop`.

Comment: Can you explain what you do that makes you think number of commits is an issue?

Comment: Which question are you trying to get answers to? The title doesn't say, and you ask about basic functionality of git that you really should already know if you are using it (please read a bit more!), and then you say "the ultimate issue" is something else. Please remember to be respectful of other people's time.

Comment: @GaëlJ Thank you. That's what I wanted to understand. To test this, I squashed the last two commits in the feature and then merged them to develop. Fortunately didn't create any conflict but if I do the same with many commits, I suppose it would probably end up in conflict chaos upon merging with develop as you mentioned. Thank you!